# Data picker result to post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have AUI Date Picker

```
AJS.$('#fieldId').datePicker({'overrideBrowserDefault': true});
```

Input field for him:

```
<input class="text aui-date-picker" id="fieldId"
 type="date" max="2018-01-05" min="2000-12-25" name="tran_date"/>
```

form with all fields and POST method:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkzid.png

```
<form action="" class="aui" id="update-tran-form" method="post">...</form>
```

I want my date to be send to another page after picking.

How to bind date pick result to POST form?

Regards

Comment: Would use the same value for name and id. Yet if the input is in the form, you should be able to access it with tran_date.